# ISNULL with Empty String for alternate still returns some NULLs

Tags: t-sql

I have this as one of the fields in my select statement:

```
select
      ...some fields
            (select ISNULL( TagNames, '') from  TagNames_CTE as tagNames 
         where  Content.ID = tagNames.EntryID) as tags 
from  SomeTable
```

I noticed that even when I'm using ISNULL and telling it to replace those with empty string, I'm still getting NULL back for some records.  It's not replacing them with an empty string and I don't see why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you'll find that the subselect actually returns NULL in those cases where no rows are found.

In cases where a row is found in `TagNames_CTE` where the `where` clause fires and `TagNames` is NULL, it *will* get converted to `''` by the function.

But where *no* rows are found at all, the function is not called (since there are no rows for it to work its magic on) and the result of the overall subselect is NULL, because it has to return *something* in that column for the outer select.

An easy way to check is to run the subquery (without `ISNULL()`) on its own and see if it returns a row containing `NULL` or no rows at all - try some simple queries along the lines of:

```
select 1,
       (select isnull (null,2) from dummytable where 1 = 0)
from dummytable
```

and:

```
select 1,
       (select isnull (null,2) from dummytable where 1 = 1)
from dummytable
```

You'll probably find that the former gives you `1, null` while the latter gives you `1,2`. Having tested that in MySQL with the following statement, you can see that this is most likely correct.

```
> create table xyzzy (plugh integer);

> insert into xyzzy values (42):

> select 1,(select ifnull (null, 2) from xyzzy where 1 = 0) from xyzzy;
1 NULL

> select 1,(select ifnull (null, 2) from xyzzy where 1 = 1) from xyzzy;
1 2
```

Comment: hmmm one would assume this would bubble up and the last most ISNULL would have taken care of that as a catch-all?

Comment: @Coffee, no I don't think so, the `ISNULL` at at one level _below_ the actual `select`.

Answer (score 1):

Because inside the subquery, `ISNULL` can only affect a `NULL` that actually exists in a row. I assume what you actually need to deal with is the case where the subquery returns no rows:

```
select
      ...some fields
            ISNULL((select  TagNames from  TagNames_CTE as tagNames 
         where  Content.ID = tagNames.EntryID), '') as tags 
from  SomeTable
```

so move it to the outside of the subquery. (I'd also usually recommend `COALESCE` over `ISNULL`. It's standard SQL, it supports multiple parameters, and type coercion makes sense)